# Dynamic use of match function

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I would like to match two data frame based on a certain column. My data frames are attached below

```
df <- structure(list(Read = structure(1:3, .Label = c("CC", "CG", "GC"
), class = "factor"), index = c(6L, 7L, 10L)), .Names = c("Read", 
"index"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df1 <- structure(list(Ref_base = structure(c(1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 5L), .Label = c("AT", "CC", "CG", "GC", "GT", "TG"), class = "factor"), 
    index = c(4L, 15L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 12L)), .Names = c("Ref_base", 
"index"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I use `match` to find the match between the two data frames

```
match(df$index,df1$index)
```

and it gives me the correct result `4 5 3` as the index of matches. But i would like to lock down position `4` which is the index of first match and perform the match after `4` or whatever the first index is. I don't want to perform the search beyond the index of first match. For example i am interested to return the indexes as `4,5,6` including repetition if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is basically not more than a loop. It loops through all search elements from `df$index` and returns the match indices in `tmp`. The variable `search_start` is used to let the next search begin from the most recent position. Since `search_start` was defined outside of the anonymous function in `sapply` you have to use `<<-` instead of `=` or `<-` to access it. There is also some code for handling `NA`s (this was missing in the first version of my answer).

```
match_sapply=function(a,b) {
  search_start=1
  tmp2=sapply(a,function(x) {
    tmp=match(x,b[search_start:nrow(df1)])
    search_start<<-search_start+ifelse(is.na(tmp),0,tmp)
    tmp
  })
  #the following line updates all non-NA elements of tmp2 with its cumulative sum
  `[<-`(tmp2,!is.na(tmp2),cumsum(tmp2[!is.na(tmp2)]))
}

match_sapply(c(50,df$index,20),df1$index)
#[1] NA  4  5  6 NA
```

And another version using `Recall`. This is a  recursive approach. `Recall` calls the function from which it was called (in our case `match_recall`) again. But you can provide different arguments. The arguments of `match_recall` are: `x` the search terms, `y` target vector, `n` recursion level (also selects specific element of `x`), `si` start index (same as `start_index` in previous solution). Again, there is some code that handles `NA`s.

```
match_recall=function(x,y,n=1,si=1) {
  tmp=match(x[n],y[si:length(y)])
  tmp1=tmp
  if (is.na(tmp1)) tmp1=0
  if (length(x)==n) {
    return(tmp)
  } else {
    c(tmp,tmp1+Recall(x,y,n+1,si+tmp1))
  }
}

match_recall(c(50,df$index,20),df1$index)
#[1] NA  4  5  6 NA
```

Comment: @AaghazHussain Added comments and improved code to handle `NA`s properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What about repetitions??

Comment: @AaghazHussain Don't your two sentences "But i would like to lock down position `4` which is the index of first match and perform the match after `4` or whatever the first index is. I don't want to perform the search beyond the index of first match." exclude repetitions? Otherwise, how would such an example with repetitions as you describe look like?

Comment: Suppose the first match occur at position `4` , next searching should not include `1,2,3` index as the first search starts at  index `4`, but i want to report the repetitions also following index `4` ie first match. The above code gives the first match not all the matches

Comment: @AaghazHussain I do not understand. Please give an example with input and output that captures this case.

Comment: For example I want to match two column of two data frames  `x= 5,7,6,8,4,6,2,2,1,7,6,1` and `y=6,2,1` . there are more than one match of elements of `y` in `x`. An element `6` in `y` occur three times in `x` and similarly for other elements of `x`. As per your code it gives the index of first match but not all the matches. I want to report all the matches but starting form the index of first match. I hope now its clear.

Comment: So what is the expected output in your new example? A vector is better than a textual description.

Comment: `3,6,11,7,8,9,12` as index vector of `y=6,2,1` in `x=5,7,6,8,4,6,2,2,1,7,6,1`

Comment: Well, this gives you the result `unlist(lapply(c(6,2,1),function(x) which(x==c(5,7,6,8,4,6,2,2,1,7,6,1))))`. But the expected result vector that you gave is inconsistent with your first example in the original question.